# Different results from the same observable when using subscribe vs. async pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm a hobbist and am learning angular by myself for an year. When trying to develop a custom pagination service to retrieve data from firebase I came up with an observable returning different arrays when using async pipe or normal subscription.

Basically, my observable uses scan operator to accumulate data fetched from firebase. It has 2 methods: init to fetch first data and set observable with initial data, and addData, that fetches more data.

After started the service and add some data, if I init it again, it will not reset the data if using normal subscription. But if using async pipe, the service resets data as expected. Why are subscription and async pipe having different behavior when are expected to have the same?

I created a simplified reproduction of the error in stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3vroi2

When click "reset data" button, the return from subscription dont reset. And the same data returned by async pipe resets accordingly.

For now, I'm already using async pipe for my project, but still can't understand why they both aren't working the same way. Hope someone can help me to figure out.

Comment: you have to unsubscribe and subscribe again after calling `init()` This article will really interest you : https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2018/03/05/advanced-caching-with-rxjs.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
 this.data = this._data.asObservable().pipe(
      scan( (acc, val) => {
        return acc.concat(val)
      }, []),
      shareReplay(1)
    )
```

This statement does not have any effect on subscribers who were already subscribed to the old value of `this.data`  - such as your manual subscription in `child.component` - they will stay subscribed to the old value.

On the other hand, your async pipe is subscribing to whatever value happens to be stored in `page.data` at the time.

```
<li *ngFor="let item of page.data|async">{{item}}</li>
```

So when you set `page.data` to a new Observable, the async pipe unsubscribes from the old (Observable) value of `page.data` and subscribes to the new (Observable) value.